# Is it bad to duplicate declaring JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript

Is it bad to duplicate declaring JavaScript variables?  For instance, given the below code, is one approach better than the other?  If so, please explain why.  Thank you

```
function func1() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var myVar=123;
    }
}
```

OR

```
function func2() {
    var myVar;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        myVar=123;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any "duplication".  The first one is interpreted as if it were written exactly like the second one, in any case.

Comment: @Pointy  So, the browser isn't assigning memory every time it sees `var...`?

Comment: Pointy is referring to "hoisting" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var - for loops don't create new scope, only functions do, so all the variables are initialized at the top of the function

Comment: @Borik no it doesn't. JavaScript only scopes variables at the function level.

Comment: @user1032531 oh I see what you mean. No, that doesn't matter. It's more of a style thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, these code samples are equivalent and will probably compile to the same bytecode.

```
function func1() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var myVar=123;
    }
}
```

AND

```
function func2() {
    var myVar;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        myVar=123;
    }
}
```

This is because of [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), and in fact you could also do:

```
function func3() {
  var i, myVar;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myVar=123;
  }
}
```

Although you might save time with `function func4() { var myVar=123; }` ;)

Comment: Today I learned about [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) - thank you!

Comment: Saving time wasn't my objective, but understanding how things work.  I know understand it doesn't matter from a performance perspective.  Is one approach more common and more adapted by other programmers?

Comment: @user1032531 there's a small amount of controversy, actually. Some developers believe it's less confusing if you do the hoisting yourself by always putting the `var` at the top of functions. Others think you should declare variables when you use them, because it helps avoid accidentally forgetting to declare them. Most [linters](http://www.jshint.com/) seem to be in the former camp (probably because it's just easier to write a static checker for that), so I am in that camp because I like linters. :)

Answer (score 2):

These are functionally identical.

Javascript takes two passes through code.  During the first pass variables are set up (amongst other things).

In your first version, during the first pass of the interpreter it will see that you declare a variable myVar and it will **hoist** the definition of the variable to the top of the scope (which is the function in this case because loops don't have their own scope in javascript).

Thus in javascript's second pass, when the code is executed (interpreted), everything will be identical.

So, **in javascript all variables act as if they were declared at the top of the scope**, regardless of where, or if, you declare them.

One of the potentially confusing things about javascript is that it has c like syntax and yet has some significant differences from other c-like languages.  And this is one of those differences.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered better to declare variables at the beginning of a piece of code (or function), than at random places. One exception being the for-loop.

```
function func2() {
    var myVar; // try to declare all variables here
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // except for the for-loop variable
        myVar = 123;
    }
}
```

Why I'd do this: because other languages work this way as well, so it makes it easier to read. For JavaScript specificity it doesn't really matter since scope works weird in JavaScript.

Main argument for this way of writing the function: readability.